# How to increment an indexed field in Solr?

Tags: javascript, apache, http, solr, xmlhttprequest

I want to increment a field of an indexed file each time the link to that file is clicked.

At the moment when a link is clicked on, this section of code (in JavaScript) is run:

```
$http({ 
    url: 'http://localhost:8983/solr/mybb/update/json?commit=true', 
    params: { 
        'wt': 'json', 
        'id': $scope.id, 
        'visits': { 'inc': 1 } 
     } 
  }) 
  .success(function(data) { 
     console.log("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL!"); 
  }) 
  .error(function() {
     console.log("UPDATE FAILED!"); 
  });
```

When I this is run I get the error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Could someone please assist me in correcting this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a CORS related error . You need to make a jsonp request to counter that . Read more about CORS and jsonp , i believe that will help you understand better .